# Getting two 'False' as output for one test value, python

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have a code that I am running, but for one input value or test vaule it gives 2 false as output:

```
PS D:\VS Code\Python> & C:/Users/zyx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe "d:/VS Code/Python/dump/dump 1.py"
False
False
PS D:\VS Code\Python>
```

How do I fix this issue and get just one False as an ouput.

Here's the code:

```
def count_rotations(nums):
    pass

test0  = {
    'input': {
        'nums': [4,5,1,2,3]
    },
    'output': 3
}

for test in test0:
     print(count_rotations(test0['input']['nums']) == test0['output'])
```

I am using VS Code.

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop. Just do `print(count_rotations(test0['input']['nums']) == test0['output'])`

Comment: `count_rotations` returns `None`, so obviously that's never equal to the value of `test0["output"]` (i.e. `3`). I don't really understand what this code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

it can give back-to-back false because of your dictionary **test0** which contains two keys so the loop runs 2 times and matches the same condition, if you follow a specific code it is the same as yours and give single False because of one Key.

```
def count_rotations(nums):
    pass

test0  = {
    'input': {
        'nums': [4,5,1,2,3],
        'output': 3}
    }

for test in test0:
    print(count_rotations(test0['input']['nums']) == test0['input']['output'])
```

if you have any queries ask me for further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_rotations(nums):
    pass

test0  = {
    'input': {
        'nums': [4,5,1,2,3]
    },
    'output': 3
}
print(count_rotations(test0['input']['nums']) == test0['output'])
```

output:-

```
False
```

your  for loop is looping twice.so, just remove the for loop and correct the print statement indentation according to it. then you'll be good to go.

Comment: I added 'Break' at the end of the code, it worked for me. Can break solve issue though or maybe break worked in my case by chance?

Comment: yeah break can work, it means that it will exit the for loop after running once. but doing it without for loop is the correct approach because you have no use of it.